# Can't modify frozen hash and cache settings in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching, hash, wicked-pdf

I'm maintaining a Rails 4.1 app and I'm trying to generate a PDF using the wicked_pdf gem.  I have a route, controller, and action setup fine.  It will display the path as html but when .pdf is passed as a format I get the error "can't modify frozen hash" and it points to a lib we have setup below to handle cache settings.

**lib/cache_settings.rb**

```
class CacheSettings
  def initialize app, pat
    @app = app
    @pat = pat
  end

  def call env
    res = @app.call(env)
    path = env["REQUEST_PATH"]
    @pat.each do |pattern,data|
      if path =~ pattern
        res[1]["Cache-Control"] = data[:cache_control] if data.has_key?(:cache_control)
        res[1]["Expires"] = (Time.now + data[:expires]).utc.rfc2822 if data.has_key?(:expires)
        return res
      end
    end
    res
  end
end
```

**config.ru**

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'cache_settings'

use Rack::Deflater
use CacheSettings, {
    /\/assets\// => {
        :cache_control => 'max-age=31536000,public',
        :expires => 31536000
    },
    /\/images\// => {
        :cache_control => 'max-age=31536000,public',
        :expires => 31536000
    }
}
run MyApp::Application
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get '/people/:id/poster/:id' => 'people#poster', as: :poster
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Poster", poster_path(@name.id, format: 'pdf'), class: 'btn btn-small' %>
```

**people_controller.rb**

```
def poster
    @name = Person.includes(:notes :vehicles).find(params[:id])

end
```

So I'm thinking this has something to do with the cache settings, but I'm not super familiar with how this cache is setup.  I've tried to eliminate the cache settings from the rackup file but it will still give me a can't modify frozen hash error when trying to render the pdf.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the object freezing when being passed from within the controller, but not sure how to unfreeze it or dup it to pass to the poster action.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, I need to post my answer but it wasn't very straight forward unfortunately.